# Why in multiselect grid with editable cell the setSelection of row not working when tries to edit already edited cell again in afterSaveCell event?

Tags: jqgrid

```
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, val, iRow, iCol) {
var grid = $("#" + subgrid_table_id);

if (parseFloat(val) > 0) {
    //alert(val + ' ' + rowid);
    //$(this.rows[rowid]).attr("aria-selected", true);
    //$(this.rows[rowid]).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
     grid.jqGrid('setSelection', rowid, false);
     grid.jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'Review', "True");
  }
}
```

It should mark the row checked if editable cell value is greater than zero. Which it does first time but when I try to edit same cell it doesn't keep checkbox checked

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help on how to do so. Please remove the excessive leading indentation from your code block (see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try  to resetSelection, before to do a set

Comment: Thank you yes it needed to do resetSelection